# Adding a Second Custom Filter to datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables

I am using jquery datatables on my rails application.
I would like to add in a second search box filter into it , i would like to use this second filter to fetch records using ajax. So basically i would an event to trigger the ajax functionality in datatables.
Is this achievable?

example:

html

```
<input class="search2">
</input>
<table class="trackable">
    <thead>
        <th>
            col 1
        </th>
        <th>
            col 2
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Js

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).on("ready", document, function(e) {

    var myTable = $j('table.trackable').DataTable({
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "deferRender": true,    
        "sDom": 'iT<"clear">flrtp',             
      });
   $j('input.search2').on('keyup', function(){
       var extra_opts = {           
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
             "sAjaxSource": "/recombinant_antibody/remote_fetch_projects",
             "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                   alert('yes');
              }   
        }
      myTable.draw(extra_opts);
   })
});
```

Comment: did you try reading the datatables docs and examining the filtering examples?

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish that? It's important to know [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the chances of getting a good answer. Please, edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Hi Guys, Updated the code now